# Solspace iCalendar: how to download only one (e.g. next) occurrence of an event?

Tags: solspace-calendar

Is there a way to only add the next occurrence of an event to iCal using the icalendar tag?

I see the previous answers on how to do this with other calendar tags (cal, etc.), but I would appreciate any help specifically for an .ics file.

Thanks in advance!
Misha

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how to do this using `{exp:calendar:icalendar}{/exp:calendar:icalendar}` (https://solspace.com/docs/calendar/icalendar/), unfortunately it's not possible. You can go as far as limiting export to a single event entry, but that will bring in all the info about the event, including its occurrences.

I suggest submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category at http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. This makes sense. I'll submit this as a feature request.